# recharts PieChart suppress pie selection border

Tags: typescript, pie-chart, recharts

Using recharts PieChart implementation, i would like to customize the border surrounding selected pie elements. It's visualized black, with rounded corners here in the tutorials:

[image]

I tried to disable it, i.e., attaching custom listeners to click events -- but the border still shows up as is, even though (I thought) I consumed the events.

```
  data: 'productivity' | 'recreation' | 'tbd' | undefined;
};

export const ContentGraph = React.memo(({ data }: ContentGraphProps) => {
  const content = getContent();

  const consumeChartClick = function (nextState: CategoricalChartState, event: any) {
    console.log("Consuming pie chart click event: Click");
    return;
  }
  const consumeChartDown = function (nextState: CategoricalChartState, event: any) {
    console.log("Consuming pie chart click event: Down");
    return;
  }

  const consumeChartUp = function (nextState: CategoricalChartState, event: any) {
    console.log("Consuming pie chart click event: Up");
    return;
  }

  const consume = function(data: any, index: number, e: React.MouseEvent) {
    // do nothing
    // e.stopPropagation;
    console.log("Consuming pie click");
    return;
  }

  if (!data) return null;

  return (
    <>
      <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={140}>
        {/* investigate on github, generateCategoricalChart.tsx */}
        <PieChart onClick={consumeChartClick} onMouseDown={consumeChartDown} onMouseUp={consumeChartUp}>
          <Pie data={data} innerRadius={40} outerRadius={70} paddingAngle={1} dataKey="count" onclick={consume}>
            {data.map(({ curr }) => (
              <Cell key={curr} fill={content: content[curr].color} />
            ))}
          </Pie>
        </PieChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
      <Legend>
        {data.map(({ curr }) => (
          <LegendRow key={curr}>
            <LegendTerm color={content[curr].color} />
            <LegendDescription>{content[curr].name}</LegendDescription>
          </LegendRow>
        ))}
      </Legend>
    </>
  );
});
```

To my understanding that should suppress the border, but it still shows up?
The outputs show up in the console -- but so does the unwanted border.

Answer (score 9):

Just simply add `outline: none` to the style in cell.

```
<Cell style={{outline: 'none'}} key={curr} fill={content: content[curr].color} />
```

Comment: This can also work for parent components (at least it works with `Pie`)

Answer (score 3):

You can add the below CSS in your global styles file or in your styled-component

```
g&:focus,
path&:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

This will fix the outline issue

Answer (score 0):

The answers above only partially solved my issue. In my case, I was able to remove the outline for the `Pie` using the `style={{outline: 'none'}}` but I had labels which still caused the outline to show up.

Fixed it by adding this in CSS:

```css
.recharts-wrapper>svg>g {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the global css, add the following css code.

```
 .recharts-layer {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

This worked for me.